# I have unallocated space in my C drive. I want to make it primary partition but it is being created as logical partition

Tags: windows, disk, drive

I have unallocated space in my C drive. I want to make it primary partition but it is being created as logical partition. How can I make it primary partition.

I have unallocated space in my C drive. I want to make it primary partition but it is being created as logical partition. How can I make it primary partition

Comment: This question belongs on [su] instead. SO is just for programing related questions, not general computer or OS support. As with any of the [se] sites, you can find more information about this site in the [help].